# Is there a Ruby library/gem that will generate a URL based on a set of parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Rails' URL generation mechanism (most of which routes through `polymorphic_url` at some point) allows for the passing of a hash that gets serialized into a query string at least for GET requests. What's the best way to get that sort of functionality, but on top of any base path?

For instance, I'd like to have something like the following:

```
generate_url('http://www.google.com/', :q => 'hello world')
  # => 'http://www.google.com/?q=hello+world'
```

I could certainly write my own that strictly suits my application's requirements, but if there existed some canonical library to take care of it, I'd rather use that :).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Yes, in Ruby's standard library you'll find a whole module of classes for working with URI's.  There's one for HTTP.  You can call `#build` with some arguments, much like you showed.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/classes/URI/HTTP.html#M009497

For the query string itself, just use Rails' Hash addition `#to_query`.  i.e.

```
uri = URI::HTTP.build(:host => "www.google.com", :query => { :q => "test" }.to_query)
```

Comment: Wonderful! I can't say I've ever seen the URI module before, so this is super cool.

Comment: `undefined method 'to_query' for #<Hash:0x1c943d0> (NoMethodError)`

Comment: @Nakilon what version of Rails are you using?

Comment: this only works if you use rails. Any alternative if you don't use rails?

Comment: Use `CGI.escape` to encode the values. The rest is simple. `your_hash.map{|k,v| [CGI.escape(k.to_s), "=", CGI.escape(v.to_s)]}.map(&:join).join("&")`.

Comment: @StefanHendriks That is not true: URI module is a standard ruby library - it does NOT require Rails. You must issue `require 'uri'` before using the code in this answer. Otherwise it works as advertised.

Comment: This fails if there are underscores in one of the subdomains of the host.

Comment: Alternative to `Hash#to_query`: `URI.encode_www_form`

Comment: @SteveMidgley I tried with Ruby 2.5.5, and `#to_query` isn’t there even if I did `require 'uri'`.

Comment: @FranklinYu - you need to install Rails (or probably just ActiveSupport) to get that method. I think this is what you want to install/require: https://apidock.com/rails/Hash/to_query

Comment: @SteveMidgley But 5 years ago you said that it does not require Rails?

Comment: @FranklinYu I think I was in error that to_query is stdlib. I'll update my response to suggest including ActiveSupport. You don't need to install Rails - you just need to install ActiveSupport which is much less "weight." Also, if you look in the comments above, there's a suggestion that doesn't include to_query that's a bit more complex. `your_hash.map{|k,v| [CGI.escape(k.to_s), "=", CGI.escape(v.to_s)]}.map(&:join).join("&")`

Comment: @tokland , could you write your own answer, because I don't see `URI.encode_www_form` in other answers and it seems to be the proper solution with only the standard libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Late to the party, but let me highly recommend the [Addressable](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable) gem. In addition to its other useful features, it supports writing and parsing uri's via [RFC 6570 URI templates](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570.txt). To adapt the given example, try:

```ruby
gsearch = Addressable::Template.new('http://google.com/{?query*}')
gsearch.expand(query: {:q => 'hello world'}).to_s
# => "http://www.google.com/?q=hello%20world"
```

or

```
gsearch = Addressable::Template.new('http://www.google.com/{?q}')
gsearch.expand(:q => 'hello world').to_s
# => "http://www.google.com/?q=hello%20world"
```

Comment: please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to raise your content quality

Comment: Cleaned it up and added examples. Thanks @willie!

Comment: I noticed that the Thor gem only uses Addressable for Ruby 1.8. Was there something added  after that so that it was no longer needed?

Answer (score 4):

With vanilla Ruby, use [URI.encode_www_form](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.6.0/URI.html#method-c-encode_www_form):

```
require 'uri'
query = URI.encode_www_form({ :q => "test" })
url = URI::HTTP.build(:host => "www.google.com", query: query).to_s
#=> "http://www.google.com?q=test"
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest my [`iri`](https://github.com/yegor256/iri) gem, which makes it easy to build a URL through a fluent interface:

```
require 'iri'
url = Iri.new('http://google.com/')
  .append('find').append('me') # -> http://google.com/find/me
  .add(q: 'books about OOP', limit: 50) # -> ?q=books+about+OOP&limit=50
  .del(:q) # remove this query parameter
  .del('limit') # remove this one too
  .over(q: 'books about tennis', limit: 10) # replace these params
  .scheme('https') # replace 'http' with 'https'
  .host('localhost') # replace the host name
  .port('443') # replace the port
  .path('/new/path') # replace the path of the URI, leaving the query untouched
  .cut('/q') # replace everything after the host and port
  .to_s # convert it to a string
```